# How can I switch between fragments on the click of a button and transfer data from one another?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter, fragmentpageradapter

This is the code I'm dealing with right now - we were given it during class and I didn't fully understand it and i'm trying to do so and add some features too - that's why I'm here.

```
MAIN ACTIVITY:
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
FragmentAdapter adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);


viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
TabLayout tab = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tab.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

That's my main activity class, which is linked to activity_main.xml. That's all in the onCreate method.

I use a FragmentAdapter with the viewPager thus taking it's parameters, eg. String tabTitle[].

Fragment class uses a different .xml, layout_page.

The FragmentAdapter class is as follows:

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitle[] = new String[] {"TAB1", "TAB2", "TAB3"};
    private Context context;

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitle[position];
    }
}
```

The actual PageFragment class:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE="ARG_PAGE";
    private int page;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);

        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Fragment " + page);


        return view;
    }
}
```

I want to add a Button on Fragment 0(TAB 1) and an EditText and using an onclicklistener to save the data in the text field, open a new tab(fragment) and transfer the data there. They're all on the same activity.

How could I go about this?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about the topic.

Comment: Such as? I'm trying to learn so I understand some mistakes could be make. This is directly the code the assistant gave us and I've been reading on some of the stuff there, but I still lack full understanding.